# VirtualBox Apache needs to be accessed from the Ubuntu host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, apache-http-server, hosts

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 host on which I installed VirtualBox VM. In VirtualBox, I have installed two other Ubuntu machines mainly with the same configuration. I am trying to achieve a High Availability cluster with two nodes (those 2 virtual machines) and I don't want to mix my Host machine in this project.

Now, I want to switch Apache service among those 2 virtual machines and for that I created a virtual host. I edit on both machines /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite and add the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost 55.55.55.55:80>
 ServerAdmin support@mywebsite.com
 ServerName mywebsite.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/
</VirtualHost>
```

This will give me the option to launch my website from `55.55.55.55` instead of `http://localhost`. But, this only works in my 2 nodes cluster and is not visible from my host machine. What can I do? Is there any solution ?

I am sorry for the long post, but I wanted to give you as many details as possible. Thanks

Comment: the correct lines that I changed are:<VirtualHost 55.55.55.55:80>
     ServerAdmin support@truenature.com
     ServerName truenature.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/truenature/
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29). The load balancer uses a watchdog to monitor the availability of the real servers and sends the requests to the one which is alive.

**[EDIT]**

You have two options: Either the clients need to connect to another computer which forwards the requests to the running server (= load balancer) or you have to move the IP address when you switch servers.

You can assign several IP addresses to the same computer. I suggest to assign two: One which never changes (for remote administration) and one which you assign when you start apache on this host (that would be `55.55.55.55` in your case).

The alternative is to start Apache only on a single host and let the load balancer monitor this fact. Clients always connect to the load balancer. As long as only a single Apache service runs, the load balancer will always send all requests to just a single machine.

To assign an additional IP address, use this command:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The ":1" says "additional address for `eth0`" ([more information](http://www.onlinehowto.net/Tutorials/Linux-Networking/How-to-configure-additional-IP-address-in-Linux/399)).

Comment: Hi again. what I want to achieve is failover IP not load balancing. I want to switch the apache service from one node to another in the cluster that I set up using heartbeat + pacemaker. The problem is, my cluster has 2 nodes (2 virtual machines). And apache works but I only can lunch the website from either one of the virtual machines, and I want to be able to lunch the website from the host machine.